# Scaling and moving QPainterPath

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to scale a [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html)?

In example my problem is that I have a [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html) size of `400,400` containing many lines and I would like to scale it to `800,800` or any other size and move the whole thing by adding an offset to an other coordinate.

Edit:

The source of the problem is that I would like to draw something on one widget and a later phase I want to show the drawing on an other widget by scaling it to the proper size. That is why I was thinking on scaling the `QPainterPath`.

Comment: Instead of scaling `QPainterPath`, scale the `QPainter` when you draw the painter path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Actually I would like to draw something on one widget and a later phase I want to show the drawing on an other widget by scaling it to the proper size. That is why I was thinking on scaling the QPainterPath.

Comment: As @vahancho said you can use QPainter::scale to draw you painter path with any scale factor. Also you can use QPainter:setViewport to make a shift.

Comment: I've just looked into it at sounds good, I will have a try definitely, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can encapsulate the QPainterPath in a new class that is derived from QGraphicsItem and call the painter path's draw from the new class's paint function.

Then all you have to do is move / scale the new item.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately I paint into QWidgets :(.

Comment: Sorry, my mind was in Graphics / Scene mode. I would expect, similarly, you could encapsulate it in a QWidget which has a transparent window and draw the painter path from the Widget's render function. Then, resizing the widget would resize the painter path.

Comment: This is a superbly convoluted way of doing things. Painters have transforms. Use then.

Comment: @KubaOber, Would it not depend upon the overall design, especially maintaining OO principles? If, for example, you wanted such widgets to be present in multiple layouts, or wanted many objects with different scale and orientations it may be easier to do this the way I suggest, rather than changing the painter transforms each time.

Comment: A `QPainterPath` is not a widget. It's a bunch of data representing a path. It doesn't have any appearance until you draw it using a painter, and that's when you can trivially (5 lines) save the painter state, set up scaling and offset, draw the path, then restore painter state.

Comment: In the same vein, a widget is a bunch of data representing a graphical object, which doesn't have any appearance until it is drawn using a painter. Why is this any different? Just because a QPainterPath is a basic graphical type, like a line, a rectangle or text, doesn't mean it can't be factored into an object. If the OP's usage is for one instance, I would agree with you that the method I propose is convoluted, but not if multiple instances of this type are required. Once this painter path has state, such as scale and position, to me it is clearly an object that can be managed this way.

Comment: In addition, why does Qt have a QLabel class? You could argue that it's simple enough to translate and rotate the painter and call its drawText function. This can also be said of other classes such as QPixmap.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I learned from it, in my case transforming the painter is better, I tried and works nice. I will try the other approach too. Thanks @Merlin069!

Answer (score 5):

This probably is too late and not complete response, but for setting offset you can use `QPainterPath::translate(qreal dx, qreal dy)`.

And you also can scale `QPainter` like this:

```
QPainter painter;
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 1));
painter.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

QTransform transform;
transform.scale(0.5, 0.5);
painter.setTransform(transform);
```

Comment: If you are using `QPainter` then definitely `QPainter::transform` (or its siblings `::scale`, `::translate`, `::rotate`) are the best way to do it, because of its reduced overhead and because they doesn't modify the `QPainterPath`.